# Array index outside of range when it shouldn't be?

Tags: arrays, vb.net

So i'm trying to create my own Item Generator for a video game i am trying to develop, everything has sort of work, bumped into many problems that i have been able to solve except for this one that i am unable to solve. The problem here is that the array i have to count the amount of item specific to the type is going out of the array when it shouldn't. I am unsure about the rest of the code but it iterates through the Weapons section fine, it's "crashing" and creating the error at the Armor section.

The context of this is that i have 4 different classes, 5 different rarities of weapons, 5 different item types and a set amount of items for each class under the different rarities.
Where this error is popping up is in the common section in Armor, it passes through Weapons. So for the commons i have it set for every 50 items generated it goes to the next class, i.e. it starts at archer, 50 items for archer class is generated and then the program switches to the next class.

```
 ItemType = Armor(aArray) 'Item type, this is where the error happens

 If aCount = (DcCount / 4) Then          'This is the counter to determine the item type
       aArray = aArray + 1               'the class for the weapon, i.e. wizard
 ElseIf aCount = ((DcCount / 4) * 2) Then
       aArray = aArray + 1
 ElseIf aCount = ((DcCount / 4) * 3) Then
       aArray = aArray + 1
 End If
```

Here's the code to the weapon's section to determine the weapon class:

```
                ItemType = Weapons(wArray)

                If wCount = (DcCount / 4) Then
                    wArray = wArray + 1
                ElseIf wCount = ((DcCount / 4) * 2) Then
                    wArray = aArray + 1
                ElseIf wCount = ((DcCount / 4) * 3) Then
                    wArray = wArray + 1
                End If
```

As you can see it's the same.

What the error happening in the armor section is that when the aCount gets to 50 it increments to outside the array for some reason. Instead of 0 -> 1 it goes 0 -> 4, i simply do not get why it's iterating to outside

I would post my entire source code but it is simply too big, here are a couplt of key points to the code though:

1. The different item array's and counts, wCounter and wArray etc, is reset to 0 after each increment of the Item Level. the wCount, aCount etc, is used for the loop that goes from 1 to the max items depending on the rarity of the item.

   ```
       For Level = 1 To 101

       'Resets the counters for each level by default
       cCounter = 0
       uCounter = 0
       rCounter = 0
       urCounter = 0
       lCounter = 0
       wCount = 1
       hCount = 1
       aCount = 1
       lCount = 1
       bCount = 1
       wArray = 0
       aArray = 0
       hArray = 0
       lArray = 0
       bArray = 0
   ```
2. Each of the items follow the exact same algorithm to generate, just with different variables depending on the item type. I'll show the weapons the and the armor:

   ```
         For wCount = 1 To DcCount

               'Generates the weapon stats
               ItemType = Weapons(wArray)
               itemDamage = Rnd((50 * Level)) + ((5 * Level))
               itemClass = cClass(wArray)
               itemName = ItemType

               addItems.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(New String() {ItemCount.ToString, ItemType, itemName, itemDamage.ToString, itemClass, Rarity(0).ToString}))

               'Creates item text file
               TextName = "Item" & ItemCount & "." & ItemType & ".Level" & Level & "." & itemClass & "." & Rarity(0)
               Dim path As String = "C:\Users\" & Username & "\Desktop\Realms\Items\" & TextName & ".txt"
               'Appends the stats to text file
               Using fw = File.CreateText(path)
                   fw.WriteLine("Name: " & itemName)
                   fw.WriteLine("Type: " & ItemType)
                   fw.WriteLine("Damage: " & itemDamage)
                   fw.WriteLine("Class: " & itemClass)
                   fw.WriteLine("Rarity: " & Rarity(0))
               End Using

               'increments counters
               ItemCount = ItemCount + 1
               cCounter = cCounter + 1

               If wCount = (DcCount / 4) Then
                   wArray = wArray + 1
               ElseIf wCount = ((DcCount / 4) * 2) Then
                   wArray = aArray + 1
               ElseIf wCount = ((DcCount / 4) * 3) Then
                   wArray = wArray + 1
               End If

           Next


           'Generates Armor
           For aCount = 1 To DcCount

               'Generates the armor stats
               ItemType = Armor(aArray)
               itemArmor = Rnd((10 * Level)) + ((2 * Level))
               itemClass = cClass(aArray)
               itemName = ItemType
               addItems.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(New String() {ItemCount.ToString, ItemType, itemName, itemDamage.ToString, itemClass, Rarity(0).ToString}))

               'Creates item text file
               TextName = "Item" & ItemCount & "." & ItemType & ".Level" & Level & "." & itemClass & "." & Rarity(0)
               Dim path As String = "C:\Users\" & Username & "\Desktop\Realms\Items\" & TextName & ".txt"

               'Appends the stats to the text file
               Using fw = File.CreateText(path)
                   fw.WriteLine("Name: " & itemName)
                   fw.WriteLine("Type: " & ItemType)
                   fw.WriteLine("Damage: " & itemDamage)
                   fw.WriteLine("Class: " & itemClass)
                   fw.WriteLine("Rarity: " & Rarity(0))
               End Using

               'Increments counters
               ItemCount = ItemCount + 1
               cCounter = cCounter + 1

               If aCount = (DcCount / 4) Then
                   aArray = aArray + 1
               ElseIf aCount = ((DcCount / 4) * 2) Then
                   aArray = aArray + 1
               ElseIf aCount = ((DcCount / 4) * 3) Then
                   aArray = aArray + 1
               End If


           Next
   ```

Edit: it appears the problem at hand got lost, here's clarity:

By default the Item type array's are set at 0 and max is at 3. When it create's the number of items needed to move onto the next one, aArray = 1, it moves to aArray = 4, which is out of the index and i have no idea why it's doing that.
By the 51st item aArray should be 1, but instead it's 4.

But now it appears that it's happening in wArray too... I have no idea why it's iterating to outside the range when it shouldn't be.

Comment: your problem is kinda hard to comprehend to be honest

Comment: read edit @CurseStacker

Comment: This line `wArray = aArray + 1` seems wrong to me. Shouldn't it be `wArray` on the right hand side, since you're referring to weapon class, not armour class? It feels like this might be the cause of the problem.

Comment: If it's max at 3, aArray = 4 is really out of bounds. Since 4 is the 5th element already when it starts at 0.

Comment: I think you're missing the point I'm making. Shouldn't the line read `wArray = wArray + 1` instead of `wArray = aArray + 1`?

Comment: omfg.... Thank you @phylyp, i completely overlooked that.....